# Delay the execution of a Python script on Anaconda prompt?

Tags: python, command-line, anaconda

I am running some scientific experiments that take a lot of time. Everything is written in Python 3 and I use the Anaconda Command Prompt to activate the Python scripts. I am working on Windows.

Right now, an experiment is running. I want to execute the next experiment as soon the current experiment is finished, however, I will not be near this computer when that happens. Is there a way to execute a Python script with, say, a 4 hour delay so I do not waste a night of precious computation time?

Potentially, adding a long sleep statement in my main python script could do the trick but I was wondering if any of you has a more elegant solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

there is a way with Windows Task Scheduler, you should see the following:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n2Cr_YRQk7o

when you set the trigger set it as you like (in 4 hours)

Answer (score 0):

While sleep could be a dirty work around, you could also make use of the innate tasksceduler of windows, like XtoR stated.

You could also call to the other script at the end of your current one, by inserting the following bit of code into the first script.

```
import subprocess
import sys

sys.pid = subprocess.pOpen([path_to_python_executable, 'path_to_second_script'])
```

Personally I'm predisposed towards writing a quick wrapper script.

```
import subprocess
import sys

# We're just providing the python path here. Make sure to change according to system  settings
python_path = 'C:\Python\python.exe'

# Here we specify the scripts you want to run.
run_script_one = 'C:\Path_to_first_script.py'
run_script_two = 'C:\Path_to_second_script.py'


sys.pid = subprocess.call([python_path, run_script_one])
sys.pid = subprocess.call([python_path, run_script_two])

sys.exit(0)
```